# "cd" to symlinked directory, want current working directory to be full path

Tags: bash, symlink

In my home directory `~`, I issued

```
ln -s Subfolder1/Subfolder2/Subfolder3
```

I then have a soft-linked folder `Subfolder3` in my home directory. 
When I `pushd` into it, both `pwd` and `dirs` show my current working
directory (*cwd*) to be `/home/My.User.Name/Subfolder3`. 
My bash prompt also contains the *cwd*, which displays as `~/Subfolder3`.

I recall that many years ago, after a `cd` or `pushd` into a symbolically
linked folder, the full path `~/Subfolder1/Subfolder2/Subfolder3` would
be shown by `pwd`, `dirs`, and in the bash prompt.  Is it a simple setting
to get that behaviour back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to [FeRD’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/690128/80216#690261),
for one-off dereferencing of the current working directory,
you can use `pwd -P`. 
Unfortunately, it doesn't work for `dirs`.

For a longer-term solution, you could define a shell function:

```
cd() {
    command cd "$@"  &&  command cd "$(pwd -P)"
}
```

(Put this into your `.bashrc` file.) 
This will cause the `cd` function to run the `cd` built-in command,
and, if it succeeds, to get the absolute pathname and `cd` to *that.* 
This will cause `$PWD` to be set to that path,
and will cause it to be shown in the shell prompt.

Under rare conditions, the second `command cd` might fail. 
In this case,
you should still be in the directory you intended to `cd` into,
but you will still see the symlink name
(and the `cd` function may show you an error message,
even if the (first) `cd` succeeded). 
Conceivably, the second `cd`
might take you *out* of the directory you want to be in,
but I can’t think of a scenario in which that could happen.

Comment: Thanks, G-Man.  I think I'm going to stick with the simpler solutions.  There was a time when I went to town with aliases, and I have leanings toward a simpler life these days.

Comment: I fell _out_ of the habit with defining aliases / shell functions when I realized they fell into two categories: (1) aliases I never actually remembered to use after defining them; (2) aliases I got in the habit of using, which then screwed me up whenever I was logged in to an account/system where they weren't defined.

Comment: Though it strikes me, G-Man, that your `cd` function could use `command cd "$(realpath "$@")"` to avoid both the double-`cd` and the temporary transit into the symlinked version of the path. (The bare, nested double-doublequotes freaks me out, but it tests correct.) Defining `pushd()` as `command pushd "$(realpath "$@")"` causes `dirs` to contain a valid "physical dir stack", as well.

Answer (score 12):

The documentation (`man bash`, search for *symbolic*) shows you can either handle this each time you use `cd` and `pushd`, or by setting a global option

```
cd -P path/through/symlink
pushd -P path

set -P
```

This global option switches `bash` to use real paths everywhere

Answer (score 2):

For one-off dereferencing, there's also the recommended `realpath` utility:

```bsh
[ferd ~]$ cd /var/tmp/
[ferd tmp]$ ln -s /home/ferd/Videos MyVideos
[ferd tmp]$ cd MyVideos
[ferd MyVideos]$ pwd
/var/tmp/MyVideos
[ferd MyVideos]$ realpath .
/home/ferd/Videos
```

Having your directories automatically `realpath`-ed is usually a shell option; in zsh it's `CHASE_LINKS`.

It's not the default because it *greatly* confuses things like directory recursion and `..` semantics. (In ways that I believe can even be considered security vulnerabilities.)

You should carefully consider whether it's really the best configuration for your interactive sessions. (In my experience, it *seems* like it is... until you try it.)

Comment: The default behaviour (of shells not canonicalizing paths) can also bite you.  For example `ls ..` uses the "physical" `..` because it's not a shell builtin, so it's not always the same as `(cd ..; ls)`.  But as far as security, if you mean scripts that assume `cd foo && cd ..` will restore you to the original CWD, yeah that's a good thing.  Otherwise a script that used that instead could be tricked into doing something the sys admin didn't want, so careful scripts would have to avoid it in favour of `pushd` / `popd` or saving `$PWD`

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh, sure, `..` semantics are already strained by directory symlinks — heck, even `ls ./MyVideos/../` from `/var/tmp/` in my example will list the contents of `/home/ferd/` instead of `/var/tmp/`, and there's no way around that. But at least `cd MyVideos; ls; cd ..` will list the contents of `/home/ferd/Videos/` and then land you back in `/var/tmp/`. Turning on symlink dereferencing quickly reveals just how often we type things like that and just expect them to DTRT, and how much it violates the Principle of Least Astonishment to mess with that expectation.

Comment: @FeRD: That's quite handy, and much more descriptive than command switches.  For now, I `set -P` (in Bash), but I can see when `realpath` will be preferrable.  Thanks!

Comment: I should mention (regarding Peter's earlier point about admin scripts/tasks) that I actually use zsh with the `AUTO_PUSHD` option turned on, so that _every_ `cd` is processed as a `pushd`. Which means I always have a full history of my working directories available. ...But _even so_,  I still found `CHASE_LINKS` mode confusing enough that I ended up disabling it.